# Is there anyway to send files to public folder from Android?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I got a website hosted by Parse.com and it has its own tool to upload files.
I want to know if is there any way for me to send files from android app. I have my data shared with my android app, and it would be great if I can send images to the web site.

Comment: What do you mean with 'public folder' ?

Comment: The folder that the web page use to store the images/javascripts/css, I think it's the only folder accessible from the front.

Comment: It would not be very clever to use that folder as public folder.

Comment: Im not "using it as public folder" at hosting the parse creates a folder called "public" and all I want to know if is there any way to upload files to there from android code.

Comment: You have to mimic the tool. What kind of tool is it exactly? And doesn't parse.com have a web api?

Comment: Yes it does have web api, but didnt find anything in the docs that allows to upload files to the hosting folder, Im using windows one and its .exe so I cant really see what it does to send the files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the Android-Library of Parse.com. 
It makes it very easy for you to connect your Android App to the Parse backend.

If you look at the docs, there is a section about uploading and downloading files.

https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#files

I've never tried it but I think this will allow you to upload your images to the backend.

There is also a JavaScript library to connect your website (client side) to the parse backend.
Again, if you look at the docs, there is a section about uploading and downloading files.

https://www.parse.com/docs/js_guide#files

You should be able to use the JavaScript library to access the previously uploaded app-images.

The basic flow would look like this:

```
Android App     ->  Android Parse Library     ->  Parse Back End 
Parse Back End  ->  JavaScript Parse Library  ->  Website
```

Keep in mind: This is all hypothetical since I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Es explorer https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop  Install this application and then select network option in that select ftp . Then connect to your ftp server using your credential. then copy paste thats it